# Cant figure out my own custom exception

Tags: c#, exception, unity-game-engine

I have this try catch block. I'm rather new to writing my own exceptions so feel to correct anything I'm doing wrong. Now my problem is that I want to figure out if one of two things is missing and pass that name to my exception. But it seems that I'm exiting out of the try before I can do any check. Here is the code:

```
string componentName = "";

try
{
    if (Constants.AllowedTyleTypes.Contains(currentTile.tyleType))
    {
        GameObject childSprite = currentTile.transform.FindChild("Sprite").gameObject;

        Animator spriteAnimator = childSprite.GetComponent<Animator>();
        spriteAnimator.SetBool("PassedBy", true); 
    }
} 
catch(System.Exception)
{
    throw new MissingComponentsForAnimationException(componentName, currentTile.name);
}
```

The two things that I want to check are childSprite and spriteAnimator.

Comment: hope you can see the exception in catch(System.Exception exce)

Comment: Are you debugging?  Stepping through your code?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer the question I just want to make sure that I trow my MissingcomponentsForAnimationException if either spriteAnimator or childSprite are null and i want to set componentName accordingly.

Comment: Is that if statement evaluated to true?

Comment: @GunnarB. yes. The problem is when I manualy create a condition to trow the exception(start the game and delete the spriteChild for example) The line where childSprite is set throws a NullReferenceException and then the code goes to the catch directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change your coding to the following and do null checks for the correct exception / componentname:

```
string componentName = "";

if (Constants.AllowedTyleTypes.Contains(currentTile.tyleType))
{
    if (currentTile.transform.FindChild("Sprite") == null || currentTile.transform.FindChild("Sprite").gameObject == null)
    {
        throw new MissingComponentsForAnimationException("childSprite", currentTile.name);
    }

    GameObject childSprite = currentTile.transform.FindChild("Sprite").gameObject;

    Animator spriteAnimator = childSprite.GetComponent<Animator>();
    if (spriteAnimator == null)
    {
        throw new MissingComponentsForAnimationException("spriteAnimator", currentTile.name);
    }

    spriteAnimator.SetBool("PassedBy", true); 
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but I wanted to write it in a way where I have only one throw. I'm starting to think that me wanting this is simply dumb

Comment: You need to throw in different places, you can rewrite it for just on throw, but then the code would become ugly, (using bools to check if not null to continue, and setting `componentname` if is null, then check at the end to see if `componentname` is not null then throw exception)

Answer (score 0):

In your code you're attempting to catch a `System.Exception` whereas from what you're saying you actually want to throw a `MissingComponentsForAnimationException`.

The code below will throw the exception you want if childSprite or spriteAnimator are null. Then it's up to you where you want to handle them.

```
if (Constants.AllowedTyleTypes.Contains(currentTile.tyleType))
    {
        GameObject childSprite = currentTile.transform.FindChild("Sprite").gameObject;

        if (childSprite == null)
            throw new MissingComponentsForAnimationException("childSprite", currentTile.Name);

        Animator spriteAnimator = childSprite.GetComponent<Animator>();

        if (spriteAnimator == null)
            throw new MissingComponentsForAnimationException("spriteAnimator", currentTile.Name);

        spriteAnimator.SetBool("PassedBy", true);
    }
```

Comment: You use `childSprite` before your null check. If `childSprite` is null, it will throw a `NullReferenceException` on your second statement in the if.

Comment: True @SynerCoder. Edited.

Comment: Another point: it will still generate a `NullReferenceException`. Currently you say: if A is null then throw exception based on A.Name

Comment: Dammit, maybe I should just stick to answering questions! Updated.

Comment: Another point: you use `spriteAnimator.SetBool("PassedBy", true);` before your null check. <= `NullRefenceException`

Comment: The line `GameObject childSprite = currentTile.transform.FindChild("Sprite").gameObject;` will throw an `NullReferenceException` if it finds no child called sprite. you cant do that either. you need to check if the reference you get back from FindChild(..) is null. you dont really need to care for .gameObject to be null, its unlikely since you search for one.